# No POS tags in newly trained spaCy NER model, how to enable?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, pos-tagger

I trained a NER model following the [spaCy Training Quickstart](https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart) and only enabled the `ner` pipeline for training since it is the only data I have.

Here is the partial `config`

```
[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner","tagger"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}
...
[components.tagger]
source = "en_core_web_sm"
component = "tagger"
replace_listeners = ["model.tok2vec"]
...
[training]
...
frozen_components = ["tagger"]
```

Now when I get entity predictions, there are no `POS` tags.

For example, a `ent` in `doc.ents` will have no `pos_` on the tokens.

```
>>> ent
Some Entity
>>> ent.label_
'LABEL_NAME'
>>> [token.pos_ for token in ent]
['', '']
```

So how do I only train the `ner` pipeline and still allow `POS` tags to be predicted with the `tagger`?

Is there a way to load the `POS` tag predictions from another model such as using the `en_core_web_sm` for the `tagger` and using my trained model for the `ner`?

I am trying to use the `frozen_components` but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can "source" a component from a different pipeline. See the [sourcing components docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines/#sourced-components) for general information about that, or the [double NER project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/ner_double) for an example of doing it with two NER components.

Basically you can do this:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("my_ner")
nlp_tagger = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # load the base pipeline
# give this component a copy of its own tok2vec
nlp_tagger.replace_listeners("tok2vec", "tagger", ["model.tok2vec"])

nlp.add_pipe(
    "tagger",
    name="tagger",
    source=nlp_tagger,
    after="ner",
)
```

Note that both pipelines need to have the same word vectors or this won't work, as described in the sourcing components docs. In this case the `sm` model has no word vectors, so it will work if your pipeline also has no word vectors, for example.

Comment: I believe my question wasn't completely accurate, I forgot to mention the other sections of the `config` (updated). I want to enable the `tagger` from `en_core_web_sm` and `freeze_components` during training so I don't have to `replace_listeners`